# Position-based replacements using Python re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Given a regex pattern and a string containing *n* pattern matches, how can I sub the *n* matches with *n* different replacement strings (in order)?

Below is a toy example along with my admittedly cringe-worthy solution.

```
import re

# original string provided by the user
# in this example the user has chosen a string with n = 3 pattern matches 
original_expression = '[x] - 2 * [y] + [z]'

# a separate function will programmatically generate a list of n = 3 replacement strings
replacements = ['(arbitrary replacement 1)', '(arbitrary replacement 2)', '(arbitrary replacement 3)']

# the goal is to replace the three pattern matches with the three replacement strings, by position
counter = -1

def custom_repl(matchobj):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return replacements[counter]

re.sub(r'\[(.*?)]', custom_repl, original_expression)
```

This code yields the desired output:

`'(arbitrary replacement 1) - 2 * (arbitrary replacement 2) + (arbitrary replacement 3)'`

Comment: Your code is working as expected right?

Comment: Yes, but I’m wondering if there is a canonical solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your replacement list into an iterator and use the `next` function to avoid needing a global counter:

```
replacementIter = iter(replacements)

def repl(m):
    return next(replacementIter)

new = re.sub(r'\[(.*?)]', repl, original_expression)
```